IntelliJ Built In Run With Coverage Running into Heap issue

The "run" is working, but "run with coverage" is giving
<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
----- Native stack trace -----

 1: 00007FF7559D39EB node::SetCppgcReference+18459
 2: 00007FF755943238 DSA_meth_get_flags+93160
 3: 00007FF7563BC771 v8::Isolate::ReportExternalAllocationLimitReached+65
 4: 00007FF7563A5EC8 v8::Function::Experimental_IsNopFunction+1336
 5: 00007FF756207970 v8::Platform::SystemClockTimeMillis+659328
 6: 00007FF7562049F8 v8::Platform::SystemClockTimeMillis+647176
 7: 00007FF756219D0A v8::Platform::SystemClockTimeMillis+733978
 8: 00007FF75621A587 v8::Platform::SystemClockTimeMillis+736151
 9: 00007FF756228E7F v8::Platform::SystemClockTimeMillis+795791
10: 00007FF755EE9565 v8::CodeEvent::GetFunctionName+116773
11: 00007FF6F641AAFA 

My script for running with coverage is working too and giving the right outputs, I just like the tool that colors the lines based on coverage in the IDE.
    "test": "node --max-old-space-size=8192 node_modules/vitest/vitest.mjs run --coverage.enabled --coverage.all=false --coverage.exclude=['**/*.test.*','**/node_modules/**','src/test/**/*.ts'] && npm run test:e2e && npm run coverage:merge && npm run coverage:merge-report",

